# I want to pass a value from one table to another in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to solve a problem, but I don't have so much depth to solve it

I have 2 tables

- Book Table

  ```
  Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('about');
      $table->text('content');
      $table->string('image');        
      $table->integer('author_id');     
      $table->timestamps();    
  });
  ```
- Authors Table

  ```
  Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('about');
      $table->string('image');             
      $table->timestamps();           
  });
  ```

I connect both using `one-many relationship`

My `Book.php` Model have this

```
public function authors()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
```

My `Book.php` Model have this

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}
```

I am able to save the author's id into book table

**MY PROBLEM**
I want to show the author's name and book name on the front end, so I tried this, but not working

```
@foreach($books as $book)
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="home-catalog-image">
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$book->image) }}"> 
</div>
<p class="author">{{ $book -> author_id }}</p>
<h1 class="book-title">{{ $book -> name }}</h1>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I am unable to show the author's name with the `$book -> author_id`, I know this approach is wrong but I don't know  what to. Please I need help. Thanks.

Comment: use `$book->authors->name`. btw you should name the relation `author` without the `s` since every book has only one author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the relation to show the author name, but more important preload (lazy load) all the Authors before sending `$books` to the view using `with()` method

Controller

```php
$books = Books::query()->with('authors')->get(); //or paginate
```

View

```php
@foreach($books as $book)
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="home-catalog-image">
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$book->image) }}"> 
</div>
<p class="author">{{ $book->authors->name }}</p>
<h1 class="book-title">{{ $book -> name }}</h1>
</div>
@endforeach
```

As i commented, you should rename the relation from `authors()` to `author()` since each book has only one author

Answer (score 0):

BelongsTo means that `author` should be singular

```
public function author()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
}
```

And in this view

```
{{ $book->author->name }}
```

You can see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) for the reference.